# Android secure/encrypted sockets

Tags: android, sockets, encryption, ssl

I created a java server that uses standard, non-encrypted sockets and an android application that connects successfully to the server without encryption.

I would like to add extra encryption so that I can transfer passwords security between client and server.

What's the best/easiest way to do this? I'm getting very confused with keystores and all that (do I need them??). I can't find a good explanation with examples of what I need anywhere.

Hopefully I get a good answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a SSL socket connection to achieve what you are trying to do. For an example of how to do this you can look at one of the classes in the OpenMobster Cloud Platform codebase.

Its located here: http://openmobster.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cloud/android/connection/src/main/java/org/openmobster/core/mobileCloud/android/module/connection/NetworkConnector.java

This is on Android and has been tested to work

Good Luck!!!!

Comment: can you update the link please. It's redirecting to 404.

Comment: Found the link:
https://github.com/LOG-TAG/openmobster/blob/master/cloud/android/connection/src/main/java/org/openmobster/core/mobileCloud/android/module/connection/NetworkConnector.java

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Java Cipher class. You could also use a number of modules, most noteably, [BouncyCastle.](http://www.bouncycastle.org/) BouncyCastle is the encryption api that android uses by default. Further you could use [javax.net.ssl](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/package-summary.html).